# Android getting orientation from MediaStore Uri

Tags: android, cursor, uri, mediastore

I can't seem to get an image's correct orientation from a MediaStore `Uri`. The `Uri` is returned from a `Chooser` intent after selecting an image from the device Gallery.

I've tried every combination of the following code I found online and nothing seems to work. No matter what the actual orientation of the image, this code is setting `orientation` to 0.

I know the actual orientation isn't 0 by checking the image details on my device.

```
public static void copyAndResizePhoto(Context context, Uri srcUri, File destFile) {
    String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(srcUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
    int orientation = -1;
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
    }
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original solution only worked for images picked from the `MediaStore`. The following solution works for ANY `Uri` meaning that no matter where the user picks a photo from, this method will fix its orientation.

The following method requires two libraries: [metadata-extractor-2.6.4](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/downloads/list) and [xmpcore-5.1.2.jar](https://github.com/drewfarris/metadata-extractor/tree/master/Libraries).

```
/**
 * Rotates the specified bitmap to the correct orientation. Note that this library requires
 * the following two libraries:
 * 1. <a href="https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/downloads/list">metadata-extractor-2.6.4</a>
 * 2. <a href="https://github.com/drewfarris/metadata-extractor/tree/master/Libraries">xmpcore-5.1.2.jar</a>
 *
 * @param uri The Uri to the photo file.
 * @param bmp The Bitmap representative of the photo file.
 * @return A correctly rotated Bitmap.
 */
private static Bitmap fixOrientation(Uri uri, Bitmap bmp) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        Metadata meta = null;

        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                meta = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream), false);
            } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (meta != null) {
                int orientation = 0;
                ExifIFD0Directory exifIFD0Directory = meta.getDirectory(ExifIFD0Directory.class);

                if (exifIFD0Directory.containsTag(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION))
                    try {
                        orientation = exifIFD0Directory.getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION);
                    } catch (MetadataException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        bmp = rotateBitmap(bmp, 90);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        bmp = rotateBitmap(bmp, 180);
                        break;

                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        bmp = rotateBitmap(bmp, 270);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error opening InputStream from uri: " + uri.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

Enjoy,
Cohen